# RavenDB: Getting exception for in memory Document Store "Voron is prone to failure in 32-bits mode."

Tags: unit-testing, ravendb

After following RavenDB's documentation

http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/samples/raven-tests/createraventests

I am not able to successfully get a unit test to run past the creation of the in memory document store. I copy and pasted the test sample found in the documentation above using RavenDB's RavenTestBase.

```
[TestClass]
public class IndexTest : RavenTestBase
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void CanIndexAndQuery()
    {
        using (var store = NewDocumentStore())
        {
            new SampleData_Index().Execute(store);

            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Store(new SampleData
                {
                    Name = "RavenDB"
                });

                session.SaveChanges();
            }

            using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                var result = session.Query<SampleData, SampleData_Index>()
                    .Customize(customization => customization.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                Assert.Equals(result.Name, "RavenDB");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class SampleData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class SampleData_Index : AbstractIndexCreationTask<SampleData>
{
    public SampleData_Index()
    {
        Map = docs => from doc in docs
                      select new
                      {
                          doc.Name
                      };
    }
}
```

Upon reaching NewDocumentStore()... I receive the following exception:

"Exception was unhandled by user code
Voron is prone to failure in 32-bits mode. Use Raven/Voron/AllowOn32Bits to force voron in 32-bit process."

I am using Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4) and RavenDB 3.0

Thanks!

Comment: I feel the real solution is not to use 32bit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the constructor for NewDocumentStore pass in the *configureStore* parameter.  This is an Action that takes the EmbeddableDocumentStore as its parameter.  Within that action you can set different parts of the Configuration, including the **AllowOn32Bits** property.

```
public void ConfigureTestStore(EmbeddableDocumentStore documentStore)
{
    documentStore.Configuration.Storage.Voron.AllowOn32Bits = true;
}
```

Then pass this as the configureStore argument in the constructor.

```
using (var store = NewDocumentStore(configureStore:ConfigureTestStore))
```

Comment: I don't recommend doing this. Don't use 32bit.

Comment: Is 32bit the only thing that is available when running in embedded mode?

Answer (score 3):

`RavenTestBase` provides a number of virtual members that you can override to do common configuration for things like this.

I create an intermediate type that inherits from `RavenTestBase` that does my common configuration and then use that intermediate type as the parent type for my tests...

```
public abstract class IntermediateRavenTestBase : RavenTestBase
{
    protected override void ModifyConfiguration(InMemoryRavenConfiguration configuration)
    {
        base.ModifyConfiguration(configuration);
        // add any plugins you might use...
        configuration.Catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(typeof(NodaTimeCompilationExtension).Assembly));
    }

    protected override void ModifyStore(EmbeddableDocumentStore documentStore)
    {
        base.ModifyStore(documentStore);
        // any common document store config changes...
        // including the Voron setting
        documentStore.Configuration.Storage.Voron.AllowOn32Bits = true;
        documentStore.ConfigureForNodaTime();
        documentStore.Conventions.DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.AlwaysWaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite;
        documentStore.Conventions.JsonContractResolver = new CustomContractResolver();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class IndexTest : IntermediateRavenTestBase 
{
    ...
}
```